# クラウドソーシングサービス等での、成果物の提出について。

Tags: javascript, html, css

成果物の提出についてどのような提出方法を取っていられるでしょうか？
主にHPなどを提出したいと考えています。

オススメの手段があればご教授下さい。

Comment: どのようなことに困って提出方法に迷っていますか？ご質問だけ見ると、[どのような質問は避けるべきですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) の主観的やアンケート系の回答がつきやすいように見受けられます。Whyを書くとより具体的で建設的な回答が集まる可能性があります。

Comment: 参考: サービスによっては受け渡しの方法が用意されているようです。[ランサーズの例](https://www.lancers.jp/faq/l1029/139) / 何かサービスを利用されている(または検討している)場合、まずは該当サービスのヘルプ等を確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

一般論として、何をどのような形で納品するかは契約事項の一つです。受託側が勝手に電子的データ授受でよいと思っていても、発注側はDVDメディアなど物理的な形での納品を期待しているかもしれません。このような状況で紛争になった場合、納品の確証が無いので受託側が不利になりかねません。

納品物の種類と納品方法はかならず発注者に確認し、不合理でない限り指定に従うのが無難です。